# Approximating the locations of the extrema of the sinc function

Tags: calculus

The [wikipedia article on the sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) gives an approximation for the (positive $x$) locations of the extrema of the sinc function as

$x_n \simeq (n + \frac{1}{2})\pi - \frac{1}{(n + \frac{1}{2})\pi}$

but provides no reference or proof.  How would I go about deriving such an approximation?

Comment: Read the article again. An extremum is not a root.

Comment: yes, and of course I meant extrema. My bad for posting questions while tired

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A079330, https://oeis.org/A088989, https://oeis.org/A079330/a079330.pdf, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TancFunction.html

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is $\frac{\cos{x}}{x}-\frac{\sin{x}}{x^2}$, so you want to find solutions to $x=\tan{x}$. Draw a picture to see what's going on, then expand $\tan{x}$ about $x=(n+1/2)\pi$ to get the next term.