# $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(\sin x\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Is there a simple formula for

\begin{align}
\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(\sin x\right)^n\Bigg|_{x=0},
\end{align}

with $m\geq 1$ and $n\geq 1$ integers?

If we expand the $n$-the power of the sine we have to consider the even and odd cases, and then when evaluating $x=0$ we have to further consider the cases of $m$ even or odd (with ugly coefficients), so I wonder if a compact formula is possible.

Comment: notice that $\sin(0)=0$, so you only care about the parts that contain only $\cos(x)$

Comment: Take the formal series
$$h(x) = x -x^3+x^5-x^7+\dots$$
What you're looking for is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $h(x)^n$.

Comment: Notice in particular that it is zero if $m-n$ is negative or odd

Comment: the result is thus a binomial involving $n$ and $(n-m)/2$

Comment: There is a simpler formula using the complex expansion of $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar one from:

> [Does sinc function have any special inverse function defined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542353/does-sinc-function-have-any-special-inverse-function-defined/4531760#4531760)

$$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(\sin(x)^n)=\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(\left(\frac i2\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(e^{-ix})^{n-k}(-e^{ix})^k\right)=\left(\frac i2\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k \frac{d^m}{dx^m}e^{i(2k-n)x}= \left(\frac i2\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k (i(2k-n))^me^{i(2k-n)x}$$

[**testable here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=D%5Bsin%28x%29%5E4%2C%7Bx%2C3%7D%5D%2C+%28i%2F2%29%5E4+sum%5Bbinom%284%2Ck%29+%28-1%29%5Ek+e%5E%28i+%282+k+-+4%29+x%29+%28i+%282+k+-+4%29%29%5E3%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C4%7D%5D)

At $x=0$, you get:

$$\boxed{\left.\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(\sin(x)^n)\right|_{x=0}=\left(\frac i2\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k (i(2k-n))^m}$$

There is a [hypergeometric result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+binom%28n%2Ck%29+%28eulergamma+k%2Bcatalan%29%5E5+from+k%3D0+to+n) and [these simplifications](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/03/01/06/) for it, but how do you apply them here for a non sum form?