# Convert to parametric equation from implicit equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves, parametric, plane-curves, parametrization

Given an implicit equation such as $x^2+y^2=1$ , I know it corresponds to the parametric equations
$
\begin{cases}
x=\cos t\\
y=\sin t
\end{cases}$.

But I don't know how to get from the implicit equations to the parametric one, only the other way around.

I'm interested in a general algorithm in solving for the parametric equations given the implicit equation. If such algorithm doesn't exist I want to know how to approach this problem given different types of implicit equations:

- Polynomial
- Trigonometric
- Exponential
- Other types and/or a combination of any of the above

Maybe some of them can be transformed and some others can't (How can I tell?).

To illustrate such an algorithm, please show me how to get parametric equations for $y\sin x+x\cos y=1$.

Thank you!

Comment: If you find such algorithm, invite a round of beers for the Field medal.

Comment: Then I guess this question shows how little do I know about this stuff @ajotatxe.

Comment: @akujack There are a few tricks that work on some curves. For instance, for $x^2+y^2=1$, let $y=tx$, then $x^2+t^2x^2=1$ hence $x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ and $y=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ is a parameterization.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, Thank you for the trick, but that parametrization works only for half a unit circle since it doesn't yield any negative values for x.

Comment: Indeed, it's often the case with a parameterization. Of course here you get the other half with $x=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$, $y=-\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ (when solving for $t$ I picked only the + sign above, you get another part with the - sign). The same applies to $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, that you can write $x=t, y=\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Comment: Only a little example: $e^x+\sin (y^{1.8})=7\pi$. Now tell me the algorithm....

Comment: This one is easy: solve for $x$ as a function of $y$, and let $y=t$. It gets complicated when you can't solve easily for one of the variables.

Comment: Parametrization isn't unique.  You could just as well have $(x, y) = (\sin t, \cos t)$.  Or $(t, \pm \sqrt{1-t^2})$.

Comment: Solving for $x$ is fairly similar, so for $a y+\cos(y) x=0$ use [this inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542353/does-sinc-function-have-any-special-inverse-function-defined)

Answer (score 1):

The parametric equation $\begin{cases}x=\cos t\\ y=\sin t\end{cases}$ you wrote, is actually the entire solution set of the implicit equation $x^2+y^2=1$.  In this sense, if we cannot solve the implicit equation in *closed-form* using *standard mathematical functions* with respect to any variable, then we cannot obtain the parametric equation either.

Let's consider the variable $y$, as a fixed number. We want to see the solution of the equation $y\sin x+x\cos y=1$, with respect to $x:$

$$\begin{align}&\sin x=\frac {1-x\cos y}{y}\\
\implies &\sin x=-\frac {\cos y}{y}x+\frac 1y\end{align}$$

Then, note that the equation $\sin x=kx,~k≠0$ (except $x=0$) and $\sin x=ax+b$, where $a,b≠0$ are types of [transcendental equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) that do not have a *general* closed-form solution.

Therefore, the implicit equation $y\sin x+x\cos y=1$ cannot be expressed by means of [closed - form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) parametric equations, in general.

---

However, the equations we noted as transcendental, do not have only *general closed-form* solutions. For instance, the specific transcendental equation $\sin x=\frac 3\pi x$ have closed-form solutions. Indeed, $x_1=0,~x_2=\frac \pi 6,~x_3=-\frac \pi 6$ are only possible solutions.

To summarize, the implicit equation $y\sin x+x\cos y=1$, cannot be expressed with parametric equations, even through any [special functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) defined in mathematics.