# Finding roots of a partially scaled function using the roots of the original function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, roots

I was playing around with trig functions and came across the Dottie Number $D \approx 0.73$ as the root of $f(x) = \cos{x}-x$. Then some time later I came across a similar function: $g(x) = \sqrt2\:\cos{x} - x$, its root is about $0.89$. I wondered if there was any way to write this new number $H \approx 0.89$ in terms of $D$ (Dottie's Number) and if there was a formula that allows us to, if given the root of any function $j_0(x) = k(x) + l(x)$, use it to find the root of a function $j_1(x) = a\cdot k(x) + l(x)$ for any $a\in \mathbb{C}$

If this doesn't work for all functions it would be good to know for what kind of functions a formula for this exists.

Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: There is a series solution for the solution of $\cos(x)=ax$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542353/does-sinc-function-have-any-special-inverse-function-defined/4531760#4531760), so an equivalent problem is writing the series in terms of one another. This depends on writing $J_n(-\frac nb)$ in terms of $J_n(-\frac n{\sqrt 2})$ with the [Bessel J function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJ.html)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Interesting, I haven't worked with Bessel Functions before but I'll look into it, thanks for the help mate!