# Solutions of a line between origin and sinx and sinx graph

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not sure how to put it into words but i was solving the values of all the roots of the equation of y=sin(x) and the line joining origin to an arbitrary point on the sin(x) graph[which i figured out to be y=xsin($x_1)/x_1$ where $x_1$ is any point on the x axis]

So: 1. y=sin(x), 2. y=xsin($x_1)/x_1$.

Solving we get:

sin(x)/x=sin($x_1)/x_1$

How I tried to solve this equation but couldn't figure it out, I then tried to search it on wolfram alpha and there were no results. I even tried euler's substitution for sin(x) but it didn't work.(obviously x=$x_1$ is a result but surprisingly if u check the intersection points of sin(x) n the line, you'll find numerous intersection points after x=4.5 ).
So is there a way to compute this ? And if so how?[image]

[image]

Comment: The site has discussion about inverting $\frac{\sin(x)}x$ like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542353/does-sinc-function-have-any-special-inverse-function-defined/4531760?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C30.3527#4531760)